# Why is the letter 'Q' almost always followed by the letter 'U'?

Tags: orthography

Is there a particular rule that states that *q* should always be followed by a *u*? Because in certain cases like *Qatar*, or *qawwali*, this so-called rule is violated.

What do you folks say?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There is no **rule** that *q* must be followed by *u* in all circumstances. This is merely true in the vast majority of circumstances, and it goes back to Latin.

The early Latins had three different letters for the [k] sound: C K Q. However, they only had one letter to represent the [u] and [w] (or [v]) sounds: V. It became customary to write the sequence [kw] (which is fairly common in Latin) as QV and all other instances of [k] as C. (K dropped out of use in most words.) This usage survived into most other European languages that were written with the Latin alphabet, though eventually the letter V was differentiated into U and V, and the accepted spelling of [kw] became QU.

Words spelled with Q without U are generally more recent additions to English, and often represent words borrowed from Semitic languages. Those languages are written with non-Latin alphabets and often have more than one [k]-like sound. When transliterating these scripts, K is usually used for [k], and Q for another sound such as [q], a uvular, "guttural k". In romanizations of Chinese Q is also used for a sound similar to the English "ch".

Comment: Good answer, except I wouldn't say [q] is "[k]-like"; [q] is a [k]-like sound only to the extent that [k] is a [t]-like sound.

Comment: @Kosmonaut, that's true from an articulatory standpoint, of course. But most English speakers perceive [q] as a kind of throaty [k], so it's [k]-like in that sense.

Comment: a very articulate reply! Thank you for answering my question and clearing the doubt!

Comment: I just think it is misleading, as there do exist variations on the English /k/ sound that we don't have in English, so I would personally reserve the description "[k]-like" for those sounds. But I get your point.

Comment: "It became customary to write the sequence [kw] (which is fairly common in Latin) as QV…" Would you know why that happened?

Comment: @janaspage Early Latin quite consistently used <k> before /a/, <c> before front vowels (/i e/), and <q> before back vowels <o u>. There was probably a difference in pronunciation between the first two, and the latter was a practice taken over from Etruscan and some western Greek dialects (who used the otherwise defunct Greek letter _qoppa_ in the same way).

Answer (score 23):

In English, there are no rules about when the *q* must be followed from a *u*.

English words use *qu* when it was present in the original word.

| English Word | Original word | Language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| quandary | quando | Latin |
| quantify | quantificare | Medieval Latin |
| quantum | quantus | Latin |
| quark | quark | German |
| quarry | quarreria | Medieval Latin |
| quest | queste | Old French |
| question | question | Old French |
| query | quaerere | Latin |
| quetzal | quetzalli | Aztec |

Other times, English words use *qu* instead of *cw*, *ku* of the original word.

| English Word | Original word | Language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| quean | cwene | Old English |
| quell | cwellan | Old English |
| queen | cwēn | Old English |
| quench | -cwencan | Old English |
| quern | cweorn(e) | Old English |
| quiche | Küchen | Alsatian dialect |
| quick | cwic, cwicu | Old English |

Comment: You should really explain that the second group are almost entirely due to the Normans being unable to pronounce the Celtic/Anglo-Saxon "cw" and so substituting the nearest Latin equivalent, "qu".

Comment: @TimLymington: what does it have to do with pronunciation? Aren't both "cw" and "qu" pronounced /kw/ in this context?

Comment: @sumelic: No, "qu" was not pronounced exactly as /kw/ by the Normans, any more than it is so by modern Frenchmen: English took several hundred years to smooth the two together. There is an interesting question about exactly which phonemes the Normans distinguished that the Saxons did not and *vice versa*: but it would have to be on LInguistics.SE.

Comment: @TimLymington: OK, I asked about it there. http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/13276/was-the-change-in-spelling-from-cw-to-qu-in-english-associated-with-any-diff